# Nginx - Using conf filename as server_name, instead of server_name itself

Tags: ssl, nginx

We're actually trying to setup a simple Nginx config. But actually, we're losing our head on this conf as nginx is doing a strange job :

We've setted up 2 sub-domains on a clean Nginx install from yesterday :

**Domain 1 :**

```
upstream 430750ef-08ce-4463-bfae-88043ffc7c82-app {
    server localhost:58033;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name 430750ef-08ce-4463-bfae-88043ffc7c82.app.foobar.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name 430750ef-08ce-4463-bfae-88043ffc7c82.app.foobar.com;
    
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/430750ef-08ce-4463-bfae-88043ffc7c82.app.foobar.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/430750ef-08ce-4463-bfae-88043ffc7c82.app.foobar.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://430750ef-08ce-4463-bfae-88043ffc7c82-app;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1200;
        proxy_send_timeout          1200;
        proxy_read_timeout          1200;
        send_timeout                1200;
        client_max_body_size        100M;
    }
}
```

**Domain 2 :**

```
upstream 820528fd-a13f-496a-b124-8973f4367db6-app {
    server localhost:58033;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name 820528fd-a13f-496a-b124-8973f4367db6.app.foobar.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name 820528fd-a13f-496a-b124-8973f4367db6.app.foobar.com;
    
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/820528fd-a13f-496a-b124-8973f4367db6.app.foobar.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/820528fd-a13f-496a-b124-8973f4367db6.app.foobar.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://820528fd-a13f-496a-b124-8973f4367db6-app;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1200;
        proxy_send_timeout          1200;
        proxy_read_timeout          1200;
        send_timeout                1200;
        client_max_body_size        100M;
    }
}
```

Actually, we're having SSL problems on the **domain 2** : Firefox (and chrome aswell) are saying that Domain 2 SSL certificate is not trusted, as the domain 2 is using the cert of domain 1 and is not reached by this one.

We can't understand why the **server_name** property is not working. From our point of view, nginx should be using the **domain 2** cert when any visitor reach 820528fd-a13f-496a-b124-8973f4367db6.app.foobar.com .

1 more specification :

- I've updated the **server_names_hash_bucket_size** to 512 as we're using long subdomains.

**"FUN" fact :**

- When we rename the **domain 2** config file from **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/820528fd-a13f-496a-b124-8973f4367db6.conf** to **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/000-820528fd-a13f-496a-b124-8973f4367db6.conf**, the right cert is served.
  In that case, we're thinking that, for a reason that we couldn't find, nginx is using the filename as the server_name property, instead of the server_name prop we've setted up in the file, and for another reason only using the first config file found in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.

Any ideas ?

Thanks for your support by the way,

Regards,

Comment: It's a long shot, but make sure those are hyphens and not some character that looks like a hyphen. As you say, it looks like Nginx is reading both files, but just not matching the `server_name` value to the value of the Host header in the request.

Comment: My guess is that how you access the server is not exactly how the server_name is specified. For example you might access it is `https://820528fd-a13f-496a-b124-8973f4367db6` instead of `https://820528fd-a13f-496a-b124-8973f4367db6.app.foobar.com`. In this case no server_name matches and it will simply use the first entry, which would explain why it works after renaming the file so that it gets included first.

Comment: @RichardSmith And again, you got the point ! I've changed to something without any hyphen, and it's now working properly. We're now trying to solve it when hyphens are set, but as we know what's wrong now, it won't be very difficult. Thanks a lot !
SteffenUllrich, we were using the entire domain when testing : https://820528fd-a13f-496a-b124-8973f4367db6.app.foobar.com. In that case, Richard Smith answer was right and hyphens were breaking up the processes, but thanks still for your help ! :)